# Network related instance specific error When connecting sql2000 from sql2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sql-server-2000, sqlncli

Since yesterday I am trying to access my sqlserver 2000 which is hosted on windows server pc. From my laptop on same network, using sql2012 and also by c# connection string. I have also installed native client 10.50 side wise. Still no success. Can anyone tell me? is there any thing new we need to do on sql2000 to make a remote connection? I usualy use sql 2005/08/12. Apart my laptops named pipes are enabled and restarted all services multiple times.

The error I am getting for connection refusal is:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This is not that simple :) I even tried taking remote connections of my fellow laptops and all is fine , but this issue is critical. If anyone can help I will be really really glad.

Comment: Did you allow remote connections from the server too? You need to enable named pipes on the server as well.

Comment: Seems that SQL Server 2000 connection support had deprecated in version 2012 and later (2008 still supports it). You may use SQL Server 10.0 Native Client or OLE DB Provider (read [this](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/12/10/sql-server-2012-does-not-support-linked-server-to-sql-server-2000-workaround/) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39572/linked-server-to-sql-server-2000-server-from-sql-server-2012) for workaround).

Comment: Yes! I enabled Pipes @samithagun  I tried to make a connection string in c# application It did not worked there even. I cant acess sql2000 from my c# connection string, WHy is this? then? ans error is same

Comment: Did you try creating an ODBC Data Source (DSN) and use it in the connection string? It might work.

Comment: yes i did but the real issue was My pc was not registered to that network. Therefore culd not access